# My PyQt5 Custom ScrollBar Stylesheet Doesn't apply

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm having an issue with stylesheets in PyQt5. Im trying to make a custom scrollbar for my QListWidget, and it works fine in the QtEditor, but doesn't work when running the actual code or when previewing in the Designer. Heres the stylesheet:

```
QTableWidget{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: transparent
}


QHeaderView::section{
    background-color:transparent;
    border-radius:10px;
}

QTableWidget::item{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(92, 95, 141);
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}


QTableWidget::item:selected{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(143, 154, 255);
    border: 0px;
}

QScrollBar:vertical {
            border: 0px solid #999999;
            background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
            width:14px;    
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
        }
        QScrollBar::handle:vertical {         
            min-height: 0px;
            border: 0px solid red;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: rgb(92, 95, 141);
        }
        QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {       
            height: 0px;
            subcontrol-position: bottom;
            subcontrol-origin: margin;
        }
        QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
            height: 0 px;
            subcontrol-position: top;
            subcontrol-origin: margin;
        }
```

When I use look at in the Qt Designer, it works fine

[image]

But when I preview the scrollbar in Designer, it appears as the default scrollbar.

[image]

I also tried running the code in python and had the same result. So why does the Designer show that the stylesheet works fine, but it actually doesn't work at all?

**Edit:**
Problem was fixed by applying the scrollbar stylesheet to a parent element of the scrollbar.

Comment: There are some common issues and unreliable behavior with certain styles and styling children of complex widgets (most commonly, scroll bars of QAbstractScrollArea subclasses). Can you provide PyQt and OS versions? In the meantime, try setting the QScrollBar related stylesheet directly on the scroll bars.

Comment: @musicamante I was using PyQt5-tools on the wrong version, so I made sure my PyQt5 and PyQt5-tools versions matched, and then tried again. Im getting the same result, except now the scrollbar is [showing a checkered pattern](https://i.imgur.com/HKNwAx8.png). I'm using PyQt5 5.15.2, PyQt5-tools 5.15.2.3.0.2, Python 3.8, Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Are you setting other stylesheets to any of the parents? Can you provide the ui file (possibly just a minimal reproducible example)?

Comment: @musicamante sure. [This is a copy of the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HewVNJEV3qD6bc8SlBs98ZzbRMrdQ5bM/view?usp=sharing) with all the essential components I used, just stripped down to only the table. 

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm using a different stylesheet than in the original post, but am still having the same issue.

Comment: Please edit your post and embed the code in it, it's better to avoid external resources as they might be or become inaccessible.

Comment: @musicamante sorry. Just added the UI code to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Ensure that you're not using generic stylesheets; for instance, in the provided ui file, change the stylesheet of TaskScreen to:

```
QFrame#TaskScreen {
    background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
}
```

### Explanation

When setting stylesheets on Qt widgets, it's important to be aware about two aspects:

1. as with standard stylesheets, they are *cascading*, meaning that children objects inherit the properties set for their parent;
2. it's better to avoid universal selectors or generalized properties;

The problem with the first point is that many widgets are actually *complex* widgets that have children widgets (sometimes unacessible even at programming level, but will still behave as QWidgets), most importantly all classes that inherit from QAbstractScrollArea (such as item views) always have two scroll bars, and since those scrollbars are direct children of the scroll area, they will inherit the parent stylesheet.

The problem with the second point is that properties set with universal or generic selectors can behave in unexpected ways depending on the widget that applies them.

While using these stylesheets is fine for very simple widgets that don't have children (QLabel, QPushButton), with complex widgets it can become an issue, especially if they have sub-controls that require more thorough styling.

This important note in the [stylesheet syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls) documentation must always be considered:

> **Note**: With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, **all** the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well.

While you did customize almost all properties, you also set a generic property for a parent widget (the TaskScreen QFrame, in the UI example):

```
background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
```

The result is that all of its children and grandchildren, no matter what class they are, will have that *priority* property set, and considering the above note, the result is that the stylesheet is not properly used, as the Qt stylesheet style parser finds that a property is set but is missing other important ones.

The solution is to properly use a *type* selector for the parent:

```
QFrame {
    background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
}
```

If you want to ensure that *only that object* uses that background, you can use a more [specific selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), the most common is the object name selector:

```
QFrame#TaskScreen {
    background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
}
```

Or, alternatively, the class selector, that maches only instances of that class but *not* subclasses of it:

```
.QFrame {
    background-color: rgb(34, 35, 52);
}
```

This is important, as there are actually a lot of classes that inherit from QFrame, including QLabel and all those based on QAbstractScrollAreas as cited above.

Beside what explained above, as a rule of thumb it's normally better to avoid styling each widget individually: you may end up setting a generic stylesheet on a parent and then you forget about it, then after lots of modifications you could notice unexpected behaviors like yours and it's really annoying to find out where the problem actually is.

It's usually a better approach to set a "main" stylesheet (set on the top level window, the main window, or even the QApplication), with proper usage of selectors and careful inheritance of properties and states, and then only change small properties on the specific widgets for which you want to alter default appearance.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation about stylesheets and their parents! I didn't know that. But I tried changing the TaskScreen stylesheet as well as adding a "generic" stylesheet to the MainFrame, and still got the same issue with the scrollbar.

Comment: @NikosBeans with the ui you provided it works, otherwise you either didn't properly set the selectors or you have other generic stylesheets (properties set without selectors or with a too generic selector) in any of the widget parents.

Comment: probably not the best way to go about it, but I ended up solving the problem by putting the scrollbar stylesheet on the TaskScreen frame, and that fixed it. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

you must make QMainwindow to apply this scrollbar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).